# display image uploaded to ipfs dynamically in react frontend

Tags: reactjs, ipfs

I implemented the code below but when I click save it returns the ipfs hash but the uploaded image doesn't show on the frontpage. Please any help will be highly appreciated!

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('The file will be Submitted!');
    let data = this.state.buffer;
    console.log('Submit this: ', data);
    if (data){
      try{
        const postResponse = await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer) 
        console.log("postResponse", postResponse);
              
      } catch(e){
        console.log("Error: ", e)
      }
    } else{
      alert("No files submitted. Please try again.");
      console.log('ERROR: No data to submit');
    }
   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the returned CID hash to construct a valid image URL. Because the `<img/>` tag doesn't support `ipfs://` URL scheme, you will have to relying on one of the HTTP gateways like `ipfs.io` or `dweb.link` as such:

```
https://{gateway URL}/ipfs/{content ID}/{optional path to resource}
```

So you could display the image using the `<img/>` tag like this:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [cid, setCid] = useState("");

  // logic to retrieve and set CID state

  return (
    <img src={`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${cid}`} />
  );
}
```